# WCF WSDL only offers complex types / methods

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, gsoap

I've found my way to WCF + WSDL. It works great in a first example with gSOAP and axis2. But I'm also faced with one issue:

When I look at my WSDL, it always uses complex types (request and response) for remote procedure calls.

```
<xsd:element name="AddResponse">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="AddResult" type="xsd:double"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Therefore I must call the `Add` method with two arguments `proxy.Add(request, response)` and then extract the actual returned value `double result = reponse.Result`.

I would like to get it more straight-forward. E.g., `double result = proxy.Add(1, 2)`. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It will always create this as a complex type if you are specifying a class as a parameter.

If you do not want a complex type to be made then you will need to pass parameters individually.

So instead of

```
void YourOperation (YourObject request)
```

You will need to do (for example)

```
void YourOperation (int param1, string param2, ...)
```

if the response is a single data type value (int,string, etc) it will do the same thing and not create a complex type.  If your response is more than one value, then when you create a class as the return object it will put that as a complex type.

Comment: But I simply declared a `int Add(int a, int b)` method and ran gSOAP on it. So I didn't used complex types!

Answer (score 1):

You should [define a contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731835.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL created is an XSD (an XML schema definition) and there it defines all the methods and types.
If you read the [following page](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_complextype.asp) you will see that the complextype is needed to create new elements or attributes.
And to contact your WCF service you can add a Service reference in other C# projects to your WCF service and then work with normal objects and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use your service it such manner and it is the default way. Just add new project to your solution using WCF Service Application template. The embedded in this template sample service contains such method:

```
string GetData(int value)
```

Without changing anything build this project and WSDL will be generated for you. Then in other project just select from context menu Add Service Reference -> Discover select what was found and click OK. Proxy classes will be generated in your project and you can invoke it:

```
var service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
var reslut = service.GetData(4);
```